# How To Expand A Textarea To 100% Using CSS Only

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a textarea tag that has text I want a user to edit. The textarea tag is wrapped inside a div like so:

```
div.container {
   width: 295px;
   max-height: 250px;
   overflow: auto;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid: #EEEEEE;
}
textarea {
   width: 270px;
   height: 100%;
   resize: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: none;
}

<div class="container">
   <textarea id="overview">
      blah blah....
   </textarea>
</div>
```

The div has a fixed width, a max height and shows scroll bars when the height is too large. All this is fine, but how can I get the `textarea` to expand to 100%? It's currently only two lines tall and doesn't expand to show all the text when I have a lot of text inside it. [Please see this fiddle to see what I'm talking about.](http://jsfiddle.net/7jAv3/)

Comment: What exactly is your end goal? Are you looking for a flexible text area, and do you want it to scroll? I guess I don't see why you wouldn't just apply the style you want to the `textarea` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `div.container` needs an explicit height specified.  Child contents won't expand up to a `max-height`, just `height`.

Something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/dpF7k/
or more simply applying directly to the textarea instead of a wrapping div: http://jsfiddle.net/ujKCf/

The only thing that is missing is that it does not shrink below 250px if there is less content.

Comment: I used a max-height because the contents are dynamic. If the contents of the textarea expand past 250px, I would like the div to have scroll bars to show the textarea's text.

Comment: The point is that max-height would be nice, but it's not going to do anything until it is filled. See [@Karl's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882402/how-to-expand-a-textarea-to-100-using-css-only/7882522#7882522).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. After I tested this, I decided to use jQuery and expand the textarea to the height I needed once the page finished loading, which solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The textarea can only expand as big as `div#container`

While you set your container to be `max-height: 250px`, it won't expand to that size unless something pushes it. Since your textarea is 100%, it just uses whatever is available.

To see what I mean, just set container to be `height: 250px` instead of `max-height`.

Comment: I could set the height of the textarea to 3000px and that would expand it to show all the text, but then I end up with tiny scroll bars and a whole bunch of extra white area below the textarea's text. I'm just stumped as to how I should expand the textarea. I can't use a fixed height because the textarea's content is dynamic.

Comment: Other websites such as Facebook have had to deal with this as well, I believe the only solution is to use JavaScript if you want it to expand as you increase the content on the textarea. There are numerous code samples for this, such as the jQuery plugin mentioned by Valoric

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you could use **JavaScript** to solve this.

This is a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery.fn.autoResize) by James Padolsey. It looks like it'd do exactly what you want.

Edit: I thought OP didn't want a scroll bar given his overflow... NVM then

Comment: @GrigoryKalabin also broken now